# Jquery, How to get prev() input box value?

Tags: jquery

```
<tr>
    <td>Arizona</td>
    <td>AZ</td>
    <td>
        <input id="item_Rate" name="item.Rate" size="5" type="text" value="1.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:UpdateTaxRate(this, 4)">Update</a>
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Arkansas</td>
    <td>AR</td>
    <td>
        <input id="item_Rate" name="item.Rate" size="5" type="text" value="2.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:UpdateTaxRate(this, 5)">Update</a>
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>California</td>
    <td>CA</td>
    <td>
        <input id="item_Rate" name="item.Rate" size="5" type="text" value="3.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:UpdateTaxRate(this, 6)">Update</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have like above table, and I want to get the previous DOM input box value when I click the update.

How can I get that?

Comment: What do you mean by `pre()`? Also, do yourself (and the world) a favour by binding your events in your javascript instead of inline HTML.

Comment: every node in a DOM tree "knows" where it is: who its parent is, what its siblings are, what it's descendants are. from the `<a>` it'd be `parent.previousSibling().child(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val();
```

where `$(this)` is the clicked anchor and get the closest parent `<tr>` then `.find()` the input and grab the value of it.